# SetWindowsHookEx in C#

Tags: c#, setwindowshookex, wm-paint

I'm trying to hook a 3rd party app so that I can draw to its screen. Drawing to the screen is easy, and I need no help with it, but I seem to be having issues with using `SetWindowsHookEx` to handle `WH_GETMESSAGE`. I can't figure out what to pass for the last two parameters.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowDrawer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private delegate int HookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        static IntPtr hHook;
        IntPtr windowHandle;
        uint processHandle;

        HookProc PaintHookProcedure;     

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern System.IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(int ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowsHookEx", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        // When you don't want the ProcessId, use this overload and pass IntPtr.Zero for the second parameter
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet =System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
            PaintHookProcedure = new HookProc(PaintHookProc);
            windowHandle = FindWindowByCaption(0, "Untitled - Notepad");
            uint threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, out processHandle);
            IntPtr hMod = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(typeof(Form1).Module);

            // HERE IS THE PROBLEM.  WHAT THE HECK DO I PASS INTO THE LAST 2 PARAMS?  I get a null pointer
            hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, PaintHookProcedure, hMod, threadID);
        }

        public int PaintHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
           // Do some painting here.
            return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam); 
        }

        private const int WM_PAINT = 15;
        private const int WH_GETMESSAGE = 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx) specifies the last two parameters thusly:

- `hMod`

> [in] Handle to the DLL containing the
> hook procedure pointed to by the lpfn
> parameter. The hMod parameter must be
> set to NULL if the dwThreadId
> parameter specifies a thread created
> by the current process and if the hook
> procedure is within the code
> associated with the current process.

- `dwThreadId`

> [in] Specifies the identifier of the
> thread with which the hook procedure
> is to be associated. If this parameter
> is zero, the hook procedure is
> associated with all existing threads
> running in the same desktop as the
> calling thread.

I'm not sure you can use a .NET dll in the manner required, but you can certainly try.

Grab `hMod` via [Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(typeof(Form1).Module)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.gethinstance.aspx) and `dwThreadId` via [Process.Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.threads.aspx).  Alternatively, set `dwThreadId` to 0 if you want a global hook (ie. a hook for all `GetMessage()` calls in the current desktop) but beware of the performance penalties.

Comment: I modded the code above to reflect your idea.  I'm still getting SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, PaintHookProcedure, hMod, threadID) == 0;

Comment: There is the distinct possibility that you need to package your PaintHookProcedure in a separate DLL; which precludes the use of .NET.  Grab the error message code with GetLastError(), and see what the problem is.

Comment: And by GetLastError() I mean Marshal.GetLastWin32Error(); p/invoking GetLastError() directly is unreliable.

Comment: GetLastError is returning 1428.  That's an invalid hMod.  Any ideas?

Comment: Check to see if the return from `Marshal.GetHINSTANCE` is -1.  If that's the case, you need to move your hook proc into a DLL, which means you need to write it in unmanaged code.

Answer (score 9):

The following suggests this won't work:

> "Global hooks are not supported in the .NET Framework.  Except for the WH_KEYBOARD_LL low-level hook and the WH_MOUSE_LL low-level hook, you cannot implement global hooks in the Microsoft .NET Framework."

From ["How to set a Windows hook in Visual C# .NET"](https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/318804)

Comment: There is a workaround: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18638/Using-Window-Messages-to-Implement-Global-System-H I guess it's better to write 2 DLLs in C++.

Comment: Thanks, @NetMage - I've edited the question to use your link.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to P/Invoke [`GetModuleHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) and use the handle it returns for the third parameter of `SetWindowsHookEx`. I also believe `0` is correct for the fourth parameter, as you don't want to hook any one specific thread in the third-party application.

If this doesn't work for you, [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) on MSDN might point you in the right direction.

Comment: GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);  What do I pass into it?  The exe name?

Comment: Pass `NULL` and it'll pull the handle from the calling process (your executable.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know but if you're using parameter values which specify that you want to, as the API helps says, "inject a DLL into another process", then for all I know it might work only if you write an unmanaged DLL from which to call it.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is an old question but I'm hoping that there is still someone who will find this useful. I think that you are mixing up `int` and `IntPtr`

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Answer (score 1):

This work for me use 13...

```
 private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(13, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: HookType.WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13

Answer (score 1):

```
  internal enum HookType : uint {
    WH_JOURNALRECORD = 0,
    WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 1,
    WH_KEYBOARD = 2,
    WH_GETMESSAGE = 3,
    WH_CALLWNDPROC = 4,
    WH_CBT = 5,
    WH_SYSMSGFILTER = 6,
    WH_MOUSE = 7,
    WH_HARDWARE = 8,
    WH_DEBUG = 9,
    WH_SHELL = 10,
    WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE = 11,
    WH_CALLWNDPROCRET = 12,
    WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13,
    WH_MOUSE_LL = 14
  }
```

**Global hooks are not supported in the .NET Framework**

Except for the WH_KEYBOARD_LL low-level hook and the WH_MOUSE_LL low-level hook, you cannot implement global hooks in the Microsoft .NET Framework.

To install a global hook, a hook must have a native DLL export to inject itself in another process that requires a valid, consistent function to call into. This behavior requires a DLL export.

The .NET Framework does not support DLL exports. Managed code has no concept of a consistent value for a function pointer because these function pointers are proxies that are built dynamically.

Low-level hook procedures are called on the thread that installed the hook. Low-level hooks do not require that the hook procedure be implemented in a DLL.

See also:
[Snoop](https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf) - The WPF Spy Utility

Or my WPF => WF => Win32 LL_Keyboard Hook Proxy w/ Gestures