# Intercepting a WM_PAINT message and acting upon this

Tags: c++, desktop, hook, handle, wm-paint

I'm trying to intercept/hook the WM_PAINT message of the desktop in C++. I'm currently drawing with the desktop handle, my only problem is that I'm not in sync so it might flicker.

What I basically would like is a statement where I can check on the WM_PAINT of UINT message.
When this is the case, I want to do something else.

I'm going to ask it the lazy way, does anyone have this laying around in a small piece of code? Obtaining the desktop handle is done with GetDesktopWindow(); from this I want too check for WM_PAINT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd check SetWindowHookEx (see: [SetWindowsHookEx in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811383/setwindowshookex-in-c) )

Comment: Ick, C# example to a 'C++' question.