# Get key from any process

Tags: c#, keyboard, console-application, user32

Ive seen many solutions online but none does exactly what I want. What is the best/simplest way to get any keys pressed in a given process (not my console applicaton) while my application is running in background. I dont need the modifiers or anything.

Comment: This is called [keylogger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keylogger) and usually is not a good thing

Comment: @HenkHolterman youre kidding right ? I want to do something with this key I want to catch it in my app. there MUST be an easy way with the windows handles and stuff..

Comment: Ok I know what a keylogger is and thats not what I want. Ill put it in other words. Im playing a game where I have to spam a button so many times it hurts so I want that once I pressed that button, the key automaticly presses itself until I release it. I know how to get it done I juste dont know how to catch if the right key is pressed

Comment: Have you tried one of those many different ways? Did it satisfy your needs, and if so, why are you unsure to use it?

Comment: Pretty much any solution I found where limited to the application itself :(

Comment: Then your question is misleading

Comment: Ok im sorry I changed it now do you have anything to say that will help me somehow ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't particularly care which process the keys are being pressed in the easiest method would be to call [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's rather limited though as it does not hook the keyboard and requires you to call it continuously. The best approach in my opinion is to hook the keyboard.

Using [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can actually explicitly specify the identifier of the thread with which the hook procedure is to be associated so you can hook keys for a specific process (see **dwThreadId**).

Here's a class that you can use (originally found on a Micrsoft blog but I cannot seem to find the authors name at the moment!)

```
public delegate IntPtr KeyboardProcess(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

public sealed class KeyboardHook
{
    public static event EventHandler<KeyPressedEventArgs> KeyPressed;
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private static KeyboardProcess keyboardProc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static void CreateHook()
    {
        hookID = SetHook(keyboardProc);
    }

    public static void DisposeHook()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookID);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(KeyboardProcess keyboardProc)
    {
        using (Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule currentProcessModule = currentProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, keyboardProc, GetModuleHandle(currentProcessModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);

            if (KeyPressed != null)
                KeyPressed(null, new KeyPressedEventArgs((Keys)vkCode));
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, KeyboardProcess lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

}

public class KeyPressedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Keys KeyCode { get; set; }
    public KeyPressedEventArgs(Keys Key)
    {
        KeyCode = Key;
    }
}
```

Implementation via Console Application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        KeyboardHook.CreateHook();
        KeyboardHook.KeyPressed += KeyboardHook_KeyPressed;
        Application.Run();
        KeyboardHook.DisposeHook();
    }

    static void KeyboardHook_KeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.KeyCode.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! ill look into it and comeback with the results

Comment: I'm trying to find what to include but I don't have access to KeyPressedEventHandler  or any KeyEvents for the matter. How can I access those class ?

Comment: Ok thanks the fix works. I'm sorry i'm really new to this. Yes I have the class but how can I access the current pressed key from a process with it ?

Comment: Since reading your comment I've been trying to get it to work but having no luck at all. I thought something like this would suffice: `var threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(FindWindowByCaption(0, "Untitled - Notepad"), IntPtr.Zero);` but apparently not. I looked up some articles on SO and found this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4974393/1500199) which is quite deterring.

Comment: well I know how to find my process but I dont know what to call and what to pass.

Comment: `return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD, keyboardProc, GetModuleHandle(currentProcessModule.ModuleName), 0);` The last argument given is the thread id of the process you wish to hook. When you specify 0 the hook procedure is associated with all existing threads.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is called a global keyboard hook. You can find more information and examples [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Oh I think thats exactly the keyword I was looking for thanks ! I hope its not too hard to implement

Answer (score 2):

Oh, so you're looking for "Autofire" in old-school gaming terms?

Instead of writing your own keyboard hook app (unless you're doing it for fun/the thrill of it/the exercise) you might want to look at AutoIt or AutoHotkey, which are both pretty good for keyboard/mouse automation.

See this thread for instance... http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/40598-autofire-keyboard/

Comment: That<s what I would have done but i<ve never played with the windows handles and keys and process so id love to do it myself :P

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to hook only for a process.
You may need it.

```
int ProcessId = GetProcessesByName("Your_app_here").FirstOrDefault().Id;
private IntPtr SetHook(KeyboardHookHandler proc)
    {
        return SetWindowsHookEx(13, proc, GetModuleHandle(Process.GetProcessById(ProcessId).MainModule.ModuleName), GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetModuleHandle(Process.GetProcessById(ProcessId).MainModule.ModuleName), out int MainThreadId));
    }
```

Remember to import these methods.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, KeyboardHookHandler lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);
```