# How can i implement the website textbox auto detect in c# with my plan?

Tags: c#

i want create windows application in c# with this plan:
1-windows application listen to user activity.
2-when user open the web site,for example google.com
3-c# detect user open google.com.
4-c# listen to user keyboard and when user type anything on the google search text box
5-show simple message box what type with user in google search box.
How can i implement my plan?I do not know what to do.
thanks.

Comment: Answer: with difficulty

Comment: Are you trying to build keylogger ? :) SO doesn't appreciate questions like this. Also the question is too broad in this format, probably will be closed.

Comment: @mybirthname no i my company buy a software ,and that sofware write with apex and can not create log file when file load with sqloader and i want read that file log in URL,

Answer (score 0):

This is far to vague a question to give a specific answer to, however I will point you in the general direction (although it's probably going to be far more in depth than what you expect/want).

You need to start messing around with low level Win32 API calls, specificall SetWindowsHookEx.

A couple of references to get you started:

- [SetWindowsHookEx in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811383/setwindowshookex-in-c-sharp)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx
- [Setting up Hook on Windows messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9665579/setting-up-hook-on-windows-messages)

Years ago I did heaps of this sort of stuff (but back in the C++ days) and found [Spy++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396(v=vs.60).aspx) from Microsoft invaluable when pulling apart applications and hooking into their message loops and windows (nothing malicious, the software was actually extending PowerPoint *shudder*).