# How to install hooks on a given window/process

Tags: c#, winapi, hook

I'm trying to install either a `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` or `WH_MOUSE_LL` hook into a certain `Process`/Window.

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookHandler fn, IntPtr module, uint dwThreadId);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lpdwProcessId);

public bool Install(Process process)
{
    const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 0x0D;

    if (instance == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        var threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(process.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero);

        instance = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, handler, IntPtr.Zero, threadId);
    }

    return instance != IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Where `handler` is a reference to my `IntPtr Callback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)` callback.

I can successfully hook globaly by replacing the third `SetWindowsHookEx` argument to a result of the `LoadLibrary("User32")` call and making `threadId` 0, like so:

```
var module = LoadLibrary("User32");

SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, handler, module, 0u);
```

How do I get it to work?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180926-00/?p=99825 Low level keyboard hook is global, you cannot associate it with a thread

Comment: @Charlieface excuse me... So?

Comment: no any injection will be with *_LL* hooks. this is global. pass `threadId` is error, *This hook is called in the context of the thread that installed it.*

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811383/setwindowshookex-in-c-sharp - _I'm trying to hook a 3rd party app so that I can draw to its screen. Drawing to the screen is easy, and I need no help with it, but I seem to be having issues with using SetWindowsHookEx to handle WH_GETMESSAGE. I can't figure out what to pass for the last two parameters._

Comment: @stuartd why would it be a duplication when they are completely different hook types?

Comment: @Henri noticed that, edited, content may be helpful

Comment: *How do I get it to work?* - what work ?

Comment: @RbMm are you sure you read the post?

Comment: are you sure that read previous comments ? _LL hooks is global only. it always called in the context of the thread that installed it. it can not be used for inject. so again - what is not work ?

Comment: @RbMm the `how do I get it to work` was `stated before any answers`, so I didn't pay attention that low level hooks are global by the time I wrote this post. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: what is your problem ? in what is question ?

Comment: @RbMm the problem is stated on the first line: I was trying to hook the keyboard/mouse messages within a given window/process, but figured that it's not possible to do so using low level hooks.

Comment: if you need hook the all keyboard/mouse messages on current desktop - you not need hook any process. if you want inject to dll to process, control some window, etc - you need another type of hook

Comment: Hi, does the answer solve your issue? Please feel free to let me know if you have any issue and also accept it if it does help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

As [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw), a `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` can be installed as a global hook only. Both low-level keyboard and mouse hooks are executed long before the eventual input receiver has been determined.

The diagram posted under [When something gets added to a queue, it takes time for it to come out the front of the queue](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140213-00/?p=1773) illustrates, when low-level hooks run.